# PhpStorm doesn't recognise web audio api

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, web-audio-api

I'm currently using the web audio api in a javascript project, but my IDE (PhpStorm) doesn't recognise any of it's functions:

[image: screenshot: unresolved type]

So i started looking for some library definition to install (in *Preferences / Languages & Frameworks / JavaScript / Libraries*) and found the following:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/webaudioapi

But after installing, things didn't get any better:

[image: screenshot: interface can not be instantiated]

Am I doing something wrong or is there another way to work with web audio api in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that *AudioContext* is an interface in `waa.d.ts`. And interfaces can't be instantiated using new() operator.

I'd suggest using `lib.es6.d.ts` instead - it includes correct stubs for WebAudio API. Just add `\plugins\JavaScriptLanguage\typescriptCompiler\external\lib.es6.d.ts` as a javascript library to your project

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately i don't quite get it: where do i find that file (didn't come with phpstorm?) and how to add it as a library (in the 'download' dialog there are only predefined options, all from 'DefinitlyTyped')?

Comment: what phpstorm version do you use? this file does come with phpstorm 2016.1.*. And you shouldn't use 'download' to attach it, use 'add' to specify a path to the file

Comment: i'm using PhpStorm 2016.1 on latest OSX, according to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs plugins should go into '~/Library/Application Support/PhpStorm2016.1', but the file you mentioned is missing. should i download it from somewhere else?

Comment: this plugin is bundled with PHPStorm, and thus is located in its install dir: /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/plugins

Comment: indeed it is. me, being a mac n00b, didn't know app contents aren't displayed in Finder. Found it, installed it, love it. Thanks a lot!